# Avoid wrapping a function argument in "quote()" when using data.table in a function

Tags: r, data.table

I have a function, `create.summary` that, when passed a column name, summarizes that value of that column by year and month. Note the use of `eval()` in the `j` expression of the data table.

```
create.summary <- function(full.panel.df, outcome.name){
    df.apps <- data.table(full.panel.df)[, list(
                                        Y = mean(eval(outcome.name)),
                                        se = sd(eval(outcome.name))/sqrt(.N)
                                        ),
                                by = list(month, year, trt)]
    return df.apps
}
```

For this to work, I need to call this function with the column name quoted, like so:
 `create.summary(df, quote(hourly_earnings))`

but this is pain and will confuse my users---I'd rather have users be able to call this function with the column name as a string:
`create.summary(df, "hourly_earnings")`

I'm guessing there is some combination of `deparse`, `eval`, `substitute` etc. that will make this work, but I can't figure it out and I'm just trying things more or less at random.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For my ( and hopefully others) sake I've lined up my answers and @GSee , @BrodieG answers according to different behaviors. At the least I've found this comparison useful.

#### for: `create.summary(df, hourly_earnings)`

- change `eval` to `evalq`, definitely seems simplest in this case.

  from the help file:

  > "*The evalq form is equivalent to eval(quote(expr), ...). eval evaluates its first argument in   the current scope before passing it to the evaluator: evalq avoids this.*"

Your function becomes:

```
create.summary <- function(full.panel.df, outcome.name){
    df.apps <- data.table(full.panel.df)[, list(
                                        Y = mean(evalq(outcome.name)),
                                        se = sd(evalq(outcome.name))/sqrt(.N)
                                        ),
                                by = list(month, year, trt)]
    return df.apps
}
```

- using `substitute()` and `get()`:

Your function becomes:

```
create.summary <- function(full.panel.df, outcome.name){
  out.name.quoted <- as.character(substitute(outcome.name))
  df.apps <- data.table(full.panel.df)[, list(
    Y = mean(get(out.name.quoted)),
    se = sd(get(out.name.quoted))/sqrt(.N)
    ),
    by = list(month, year, trt)
  ]
  df.apps
}
```

---

#### for: `create.summary(df, "hourly_earnings")`

- `get()` searches for object of that name; it is safer than *`parse(text=)`*

Your function becomes:

```
create.summary <- function(full.panel.df, outcome.name){
    df.apps <- data.table(full.panel.df)[, list(
                                        Y = mean(get(outcome.name)),
                                        se = sd(get(outcome.name))/sqrt(.N)
                                        ),
                                by = list(month, year, trt)]
    return df.apps
}
```

- `parse(text=)` which is useful for *synthesizing* expressions / reading from file.

Your function becomes:

```
create.summary <- function(full.panel.df, outcome.name){
    df.apps <- data.table(full.panel.df)[, list(
                                        Y = mean(eval(parse(text=outcome.name))),
                                        se = sd(eval(parse(text=outcome.name)))/sqrt(.N)
                                        ),
                                by = list(month, year, trt)]
    return df.apps
}
```

---

Comment: What if you have a column named "system(rm -rf ./)"?

Comment: @GSee oy. this would be bad. I've never thought of this ( I actually did not know about `get()` (hence +1). I'm trying to get a better understanding of non-std eval in R any resources I could be pointed to ? ps. should I delete this answer?

Comment: I don't think this is such a big deal with functions that are run by a user on their own terminal with their own permissions, which is typically the case with most R packages.  They could after all just type "command that blows up my own system" instead of passing it to a 3rd party function.  If you're capturing input from the web and then running it on you server, then that's a different story.

Answer (score 3):

Try using `get` instead of `eval`

```
create.summary <- function(full.panel.df, outcome.name){
    df.apps <- data.table(full.panel.df)[, list(
                                        Y = mean(get(outcome.name)),
                                        se = sd(get(outcome.name))/sqrt(.N)
                                        ),
                                by = list(month, year, trt)]
    return df.apps
}
```

Here's a reproducible example:

```
foo <- function(x, n) {
  data.table(x)[, list(Y=mean(get(n)),
                       se=sd(get(n))/sqrt(.N)),
                by=list(cyl, am)]
}

foo(mtcars, "wt")
#    cyl am        Y         se
# 1:   6  1 2.755000 0.07399324
# 2:   4  1 2.042250 0.14472656
# 3:   6  0 3.388750 0.05810820
# 4:   8  0 4.104083 0.22179111
# 5:   4  0 2.935000 0.23528352
# 6:   8  1 3.370000 0.20000000
foo(mtcars, "hp")
#    cyl am         Y        se
# 1:   6  1 131.66667 21.666667
# 2:   4  1  81.87500  8.009899
# 3:   6  0 115.25000  4.589390
# 4:   8  0 194.16667  9.630156
# 5:   4  0  84.66667 11.348030
# 6:   8  1 299.50000 35.500000
```

Answer (score 1):

And another using `substitute` and `get`:

```
create.summary <- function(full.panel.df, outcome.name){
  out.name.quoted <- as.character(substitute(outcome.name))
  df.apps <- data.table(full.panel.df)[, list(
    Y = mean(get(out.name.quoted)),
    se = sd(get(out.name.quoted))/sqrt(.N)
    ),
    by = list(month, year, trt)
  ]
  df.apps
}
```

Usage:

```
create.summary(df, a)
```

With some data:

```
df <- data.frame(month=month.abb, year=rep(2000:2005, each=24), trt=c("one", "two"), a=runif(6 * 12), b=runif(6 * 12))
```

Comment: Ok, except the OP says "I'd rather have users be able to call this function with the column name as a string: create.summary(df, "hourly_earnings")"

Comment: @GSee, I think the OP is saying the rather relative to the need to `quote` the variable name (i.e., it would be more desirable to have "var.name" than `quote(var.name)`).  It isn't obvious to me that to the OP "var.name" is clearly better than `var.name`.  The latter is what many users are familiar with when using `subset`, etc., so it seems like a reasonable alternative approach.  I'm not making any claims as to this being superior to just the character version.